# Azure pipelines - running a self-hosted agent behind firewall

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to set up a self-hosted agent behind a firewall. I tried to get the IPs or URLs to be whitelisted so the agent will be able to communicate with Azure DevOps services.

I tried this [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#im-running-a-firewall-and-my-code-is-in-azure-repos-what-urls-does-the-agent-need-to-communicate-with) which has information on the URLs and IPs required to whitelist. It actually works except the DownloadPipelineArtifact task is failing. I guess I need to whitelist additional URLs.?! if yes, kindly point me to the official documentation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Dhan, How about this issue? Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Hi Edward, it solves the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops#azure-artifacts), you need to add additional URL “https://*.visualstudio.com” into the whitelist.

In addition, if you have set up any IP restriction on your self-hosted agent machine, you need to weekly check and update the Azure IP ranges from the [weekly file](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D56519&data=04%7C01%7Cv-brira%40microsoft.com%7C2a0129a429db43a5219c08d8ed1c8c5d%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637520054157588035%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=PWA%2B89VGl9iiTPS70uFK3PfJvnLb1dN6d21gb%2FvQQv4%3D&reserved=0) into the whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

As this doc: [Run a self-hosted agent behind a web proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) stated, the agent will talk to Azure DevOps/TFS service through the web proxy specified in the `.proxy` file.

Since the code for the `Get Source` task in builds and `Download Artifact` task in releases are also baked into the agent, those tasks will follow the agent proxy configuration from the `.proxy` file.